# Removing duplicate lines with PowerShell takes much longer than WSL

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

I have a huge file around 45M lines, size around 1GB.

I use this command in my WSL and it takes around 2 minutes to remove duplicate lines and the new file has around 13M lines:

```
root@DESKTOP-9PR0R3P:/mnt/c/Users/Saeed/Desktop/p/test# date; awk '!seen[$0]++' huge.txt > new2.txt; date
Sat May 20 10:58:06 +0330 2023
Sat May 20 11:00:10 +0330 2023
```

But I use this command in PowerShell and after around 15 minutes I have no results (even the file size is still 0 byte and not higher than that):

```
gc huge.txt | sort | get-unique > new.txt
```

Is there any difference between `awk` and `sort` and `get-unique` in Bash and PowerShell for this?

I tried the PowerShell command with smaller file and it worked (I mean the command itself is correct).

Comment: Try this: `[IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD\huge.txt") | Sort-Object -Unique >new.txt`

Comment: @zett42 it finished after around 15 minutes in a file with less lines:(

Comment: Well, the awk code isn't sorting the results, which can take quite a bit of time for huge inputs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`Linq.Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0) method in combination with [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) functions seems to be pretty fast:

```bash
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$PWD\new.txt",
    [Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct(
        [IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD\input_big.txt")
    )
)
```

On my machine, this takes about **1 sec** for a text file with 5M lines (305 MB).

This eliminates the PowerShell pipeline completely by using only .NET functions. Also, no file data is passed through PowerShell, as all of the functions work with `IEnumerable`'s. That's propably as fast as you can get using a .NET language.

Comment: Your answer is much more faster than @Shawn's. Your method is done within 30 seconds:)

Comment: @Saeed Awesome! I didn't expect it to be even faster than your awk command.

Answer (score 2):

Your `awk` and powershell commands are very different. The `awk` just saves each line read in a hash table and prints it if it's not already in the table. The powershell pipeline has to read the entire file, sort it, remove duplicates, and then write the remaining elements out. No wonder it's taking a lot longer.

A powershell equivalent to what the `awk` script is doing might look something like:

```
function Remove-Duplicates {
  param ( $filename )
  $seen = @{}
  ForEach ($line in Get-Content -Path $filename) {
    if (!$seen.Contains($line)) {
      $seen.Add($line, 1)
      Write-Output $line
    }
  }
}

Remove-Duplicates huge.txt | Set-Content -Path new.txt
```

Comment: There are probably better ways; I'm far from knowledgeable about powershell.

Comment: I'm grateful for the answer, but @zett42's answer is very fast. You answer is still running with no output after around 30 minutes.

Comment: I figured it'd be within the same ballpark as awk. Clearly I'm making some incorrect assumptions about how a few things work in ps. I really should actually learn it one of these days...

Comment: PowerShell-native solutions will always be slower, but `Get-Content` is particularly slow: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537. A faster alternative is the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, for which `awk` was the inspiration.

Comment: An advantage of using PowerShell is that you might conserve memory if you *correctly* implement the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines): `$HashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::new(); Get-Content  -Path $Filename |Where-Object { $HashSet.Add($_.) } |Set-Content -Path .\new.txt`.